# MUI V5, how to minify class names in production build

Tags: material-ui, minify, production, classname

How is possible to there is no option to minify the prod class names? It is a a big step back. Please say me that I am not right.

In Material v4 can be achieved with 3 simple rules:

- Only one theme provider is used (No theme nesting)
- The style sheet has a name that starts with Mui (all Material-UI components).
- The disableGlobal option of the class name generator is false (the default).

In v5.5 in my experiment I don`t use any custom styles, just default provided from MUI components.

```
"react": "^18.0.0",
"react-dom": "^18.0.0",
"@emotion/react": "^11.8.1",
"@mui/material": "^5.5.2"
```

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@mui/material/styles'

<ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    <Component {...this.props} />
</ThemeProvider>
```

```
import { Paper, Grid, Typography, Box } from '@mui/material'

<Grid container component={'main'}>
    <Grid item xs={false} sm={4} md={8} />
    <Grid item xs={12} sm={8} md={4} component={Paper} elevation={6} square>
        <Typography component={'h1'} variant={'h4'} align={'center'}>
            <Box fontWeight={'fontWeightLight'} m={1}>
                {'MY ACCOUNT'}
            </Box>
        </Typography>
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

In production build I expect to be something like this:

```
jss1 jss2 jss3 jss4 jss5 jss6 and etc...
```

but the result is:

```
MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-container css-1d3bbye
```

```
MuiGrid-root MuiGrid-item MuiGrid-grid-sm-4 MuiGrid-grid-md-8 css-18mwvdj
```

Comment: still no solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think i found it
https://v5-0-6.mui.com/guides/classname-generator/

Converts from

```
<button
  class="MuiButton-root MuiButton-text MuiButton-textPrimary MuiButton-sizeMedium MuiButton-textSizeMedium MuiButtonBase-root css-1ujsas3"
>
  Button
</button>
```

to

```
<button
  class="foo-bar-MuiButton-root foo-bar-MuiButton-text foo-bar-MuiButton-textPrimary foo-bar-MuiButton-sizeMedium foo-bar-MuiButton-textSizeMedium foo-bar-MuiButtonBase-root css-1ujsas3"
>
  Button
</button>
```

I have just tried it with latest MUIv5 and works great.